# onCreateOptionsMenu do not call after popbackstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

I replace one Fragment 1 by Fragment 2 by menu clicking:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    if (savedItemsExist()) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_call_to_delete_filter) {
            SavedFiltersDeleteFragment newFragment = new SavedFiltersDeleteFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and in Fragment 2 I want to return to previous Fragment by :

```
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

But when I appear at the Fragment 1 , I see the menu from the Fragment 2.

So the `onCreateOptionsMenu` not being called in Fragment 1. I update the UI of Fragment 1 in the `onStart()` method, so how can I update the menu ?

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        if (savedItemsExist())
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_saved_filters, menu);

    }
```

I also call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in the `onStart()` method of the Fragment 1.

```
 this.setHasOptionsMenu(true); also added in `onCreate()` of the Fragment 1.
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I solved it with replacing and commting the new `Fragment` instead of the `popBackStack`

Comment: This is not a physible solution, it's create a new fragment on every time when you come back to that fragment and open as fresh fragment. I face the same problem but don't want to recreate the fragment.